# Declining comment flags and then deleting. Reason?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

After making necessary edits, and flagging unrelated comments (today's 1-2 hours ago), why were two of my "no longer required" comment flags declined and then one of those was deleted anyway in my post:

[What is the minimum salary possible in a government department job in the United Kingdom?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68108/what-is-the-minimum-salary-possible-in-a-government-department-job-in-the-united)

[image: 20210813-194159.png]

I am not here to attack any moderator. I just wanted to know legit reasons, if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I declined the first two flags at first because those comments were criticism of the question. Getting moderators to remove comments is not a way to deal with criticism you don't agree with.

But after reading further comments, it became apparent that these triggered an off-topic discussion which I subsequently nuked. So those comments still ended up deleted eventually.